# Communication protocol

Tags: sockets, unix, tcp, distributed-system

I'm developing distributed system that consists of master and worker servers. There should be 2 kind of messages:

**Heartbeat**

Master gets state of worker and respond immediately with appropriate command. For instance:

1. Message from *Worker* to *Master*: "Hey there! I have data a,b,c"
2. Response from *Master* to *Worker*: "All ok, But throw away c - we dont need this anymore"

The participants exchange this messages with interval T.

**Direct master command**

Lets say client asks master to kill job #123. Here is conversation:

1. Message from *Master* to *Worker*: "Alarm! We need to kill job #123"
2. Message from *Worker* to *Master*: "No problem! Done."

Obvious that we can't predict when this message appear.

---

Simplest solution is that *master* is initiator of all communications for both messages (in case of heartbeat we will include another one from *master* to  start exchange). But lets assume that it is expensive to do all heartbeat housekeeping on *master* side for N *workers*. And we don't want to waste our resources to keep several tcp connections to worker servers so we have just one.

Is there any solution for this constraints?

Comment: The first message isn't really a "heartbeat". A "heartbeat" message is basically nothing more than an message saying "I'm still alive", and the answer to that is "Good, so am I". It's a little more complicated than that though, because if the master doesn't get a heartbeat from a worker in some time, how can it know that it's the *worker* that's gone, and not the masters network connection that is down?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you are right "heartbeat" term is not correct. I use it from this paper http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/ru//archive/gfs-sosp2003.pdf (my hobby project based on it)

Comment: Bit confused. "Lets say client asks master to kill job #123. Here is conversation:" Then why is Master saying "Alarm! We need to kill job #123" and client "No problem! Done."?

Comment: @Prabhu worker is not the client, client is the user of whole system.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you have to do *some* bookkeeping *somewhere*. Otherwise, who's going to realize that a worker has died? The natural place to put that data is on the master, if you're building a master/worker system. Otherwise, the workers could be asked to keep track of each other in a long circle, or a randomized graph. If a worker notices that their accountabilibuddy is not responding anymore, it can alert the master.

Same thing applies to the list of jobs currently running; who keeps track of that? It also scales O(n), so presumably the master doesn't have space for that either. Sharding that data out among the workers (e.g. by keeping track of what things their accountabilibuddy is supposed to be doing) only works so far; if `a` and `b` crashes, and `a` is the only one looking after `b`, you just lost the list of jobs running on `b` (and possibly the alert that was supposed to notify you that `b` crashed).

I'd recommend a distributed consensus algorithm for this kind of task. For production, use something someone else has already written; they probably know what they're doing. If it's for learning purposes, which I presume, have a look at the [raft consensus algorithm](https://raft.github.io/). It's not too hard to understand, but still highlights a lot of the complexity in distributed systems. The simulator is gold for proper understanding.

A master/worker system will never properly work with less than `O(n)` resources for `n` workers in the face of crashing workers. By definition, the master needs to control the workers, which is an `O(n)` job, even if some workers manage other workers. Also, what happens if the master crashes?

Answer (score 0):

Like Filip Haglund said read the raft paper you should also implement it yourself. However in a nutshell what you need to extract from it would be this. In regaurds to membership management.

You need to keep membership lists and the masters Identity on all nodes.

Raft does it's heartbeat sending on master's end it is not very expensive network wise you don't need to keep them open. Every 200 ms to a second you need to send the heartbeat if they don't reply back the Master tells the slaves remove member x from list.

However what what to do if the master dies well basically you need to preset candidate nodes. If you haven't received a heart beat within the timeout the candidate requests votes from the rest of the cluster. If you get the slightest majority you become the new leader.

If you want to join a existing cluster basically same as above if not leader respond not leader with leaders address.